# Deriving sampling distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling, asymptotics

Assume we have the following function:

$$f(p) = \frac{1}{(1-p)d}\ln\left(\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\left[\frac{1+X_t}{1+Y_t} \right]^{1-p} \right)$$

where

$d$ is a constant

$T$ is a constant

$X_t$ for $t = 1, 2, \cdots, T$ are random variables

$Y_t$ for $t = 1, 2, \cdots, T$ are random variables

$p$ is defined such that it is value that satisfies $f(p) = 0$

I wish to derive a sampling distribution for the statistic $p$.

By sampling distribution I mean the following:

The solution to $f(p) = 0$ doesn't have a closed-form solution, but it is obvious that the resulting value of $p$ depends on $X_t$ and $Y_t$, so $p$ can be treated as a random variable that depends on the random variables $X_t$ and $Y_t$. Then for every $T$ observations of $X_t$ and $Y_t$, we have a corresponding value $p$ that satisfies $f(p) = 0$, what is the sampling distribution of $p$?

Also assume you are allowed the following assumptions to achieve the above:

1) You can make any distributional assumptions regarding $X_t$ and $Y_t$, e.g., $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are independent from each other, also $X_t$, $Y_t$ for $t = 1, 2, \cdots, T$ are independently and identically distributed.

2) Rather than making distributional assumptions about $X_t$ and $Y_t$, assume you can make some assumptions about the processes $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$, e.g., both processes are stationary (or weakly stationary) etc.

---

EDIT: Update on my progress.

So if we let $Z_t = \frac {1 + X_t} {1 + Y_t}$, then we have $f(p) = \frac {1} {(1 - p)d} \ln\left(\frac {1} {T} \sum_{i=1}^T Z_t^{1-p} \right)$. Setting this equation to $0$ and rearranging, we have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^T Z_t^{1-p} = T$$

Thus, for a fixed $T$, what is the distribution of $p$?

Comment: Not sure I see how the distribution of $p$ depends on $n$. As I  read it, $n$ is just the number of times you observe $p(X,Y)$, but a RV doesn't change its distribution just because you sample it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Karl Oskar, Ah yes good point you are right, sorry that must have been my own misunderstanding. Ok so I guess I am just after the distribution of $p(X,Y)$...